# Something strange for my texture in fragment shader

Tags: opengl

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 param_uv;
uniform sampler2D uniform_texturetoto;
out vec3 color;
void main()
{
    color = texture( uniform_texturetoto, param_uv ).rgb;
}
```

and here is a piece of my main c++ code:

```
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture->w, texture->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, my_texture_pixels);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

...

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
```

My problem is that everything works fine. And this is not normal because uniform_texturetoto is never used in my main c++ program. I can replace uniform_texturetoto by any variable name and the program still works !

My question is... Why ?

Thanks

Comment: are you saying that you are not calling glGetUniformLocation() for uniform_texturetoto and you are not binding it to any texture unit and still code is working?

Comment: The default value of a sampler uniform will most probably be 0. Since you have your texture bound to texture unit 0 everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think GLSL specs has answer for it

Using the 4.50 spec, section 4.3.5 has the answer:

All uniform variables are read-only and are initialized externally either at link time or through the API. The link-time initial value is either the value of the variable's initializer, if present, or 0 if no initializer is present.

I think thats why you code is working fine.